# Every subdomain redirect to main one

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have bought VPS server and domain that points to IP of that vps. I thought everything was working fine however i noticed that when i ping:
`ping domain.com
ping asd.domain.com
ping asd.asd.asd.asd.domain.com`
it gives always same result (pings my vps) and i guess it shouldn't do that (only domain.com). I'm using Ubuntu 16 on vps without any special configuration. So do i need to set up dns server or something on my server? Is this natural behaviour? How to "fix" this and how to manage subdomains?

Comment: This usually has nothing to do with VPS, name resolution is managed at DNS service hosting provider (which may be the place where you purchased your domain name, or the place where you bought your VPS, or any third-party DNS service provider)

Comment: Who is hosting your DNS now? If you check in there control panel you will almost certainly find that `domain.com` is wild-carded with a `*`